# Decode UDP Packet to Netflow

Tags: python, scapy, netflow

I've come across the Wireshark `decode as` feature where I can decode UDP packet as `CFLOW` to get my Netflow data.

Is it possible to code a script that decode the UDP Packet and get the Netflow data?

> Currently I am trying it out using python3-scapy. Where I sniff the
>   interface and retrieve only UDP packet. I am stuck now as I don't know
>   what I should do next.
>
> Note: My focus is on Netflow Version 9

Below is my code:

```
from scapy.all import *

## Create a Packet Counter
counter = 0
INTERFACE = "<interface_name>"

## Define our Custom Action function
def custom_action(pkts):
    for packet in pkts:
        if (packet.haslayer(UDP)):
             # do something , what should i do?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ## Setup sniff, filtering for IP traffic
    sniff(iface=INTERFACE, prn = custom_action, store=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can use `layer in pkt` rather than the "old" `pkt.haslayer(layer)`. This will work with the [development version of Scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy) (which works with Python 3).

The `prn` callback accepts a packet, not a packet list or generator.

If you want to use `NetflowHeader()` to (try to) dissect any UDP packet, you can do:

```
def custom_action(pkt):
    if UDP in pkt:
        pkt[UDP].payload = NetflowHeader(raw(pkt[UDP].payload))

pkts = sniff(iface=INTERFACE, prn=custom_action)
```

But the closest way to Wireshark's "decode as" functionality in Scapy would be to simply overwrite `UDP`'s `.payload_guess` attribute:

```
UDP.payload_guess = [({}, NetflowHeader)] 
pkts = sniff(iface=INTERFACE)
```

Comment: Where can I get the `NetflowHeader()` and what are the usage?

p.s. I am fairly new to scapy. 

thank you

Comment: `NetflowHeader()` is the Scapy layer that you need to use to decode data as Netflow. Get the latest version from https://github.com/secdev/scapy.

Comment: Thanks! I manage to make the NetflowHeader() works. As I read the documentation for Netflow v9 for scapy. Does it mean when I want to decode UDP packet to Netflow v9 i just have to change this to this instead: 
`pkt[UDP].payload = NetflowHeaderV9(Raw(pkt[UDP].payload))`? It will return me the Raw Netflow v9 object. Is that it?

Comment: No. You will see `NetflowHeaderV9` layers when the `NetflowHeader` decodes version as 9. A NetflowHeader should start with the version number.